# How to load/animate the listbox items dynamically

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7.1

I'm developing an application in windows phone 7.1. In my application I have a listbox which has more than 100 user details. I'm displaying each user detail as a rectangle block - (Image and three textblocks). The image and rectangle block has animation effects.

When displaying the details on the phone screen,  I can show upto 5 rectangle blocks (only). My problem is the remaining blocks are still animated though they are not displayed to the user. Also all the blocks are loaded while the page is loading. I think its not good practice to do it in this way.

I want to know,

1. Is there anyway I can load the listbox dynamically as the user scroll through the listbox.
2. How to animate only the active blocks showed to the user.

Comment: do you use a virtualizing stack panel on your listbox? it can optimize your listbox. However, i dont see any implementation(maybe hidden by the api) on how to control or fire events when a listbox item is active/visible.

Comment: @xiriusly thanks for the reply. I will try to use virtualizing stack panel and see how it works.

Comment: actually, when you declare a stackpanel inside the datatemplate of your listbox, its already virtualized